# Is there a way to tell if a table is being referenced in another Database/Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am building a **personal use** PHP script using the `MSSQL` driver in PDO (as such there is **no plan to let anyone else but me** use this) which when provided with a table name will return all objects that referenced it

using `MySVR.MyDB.dbo.Staff` as my table i first start with this query

```
SELECT
    referencing_schema_name = SCHEMA_NAME(o.SCHEMA_ID),
    referencing_object_name = o.name,
    referencing_object_type_desc = o.type_desc,
    referenced_schema_name,
    referenced_object_name = referenced_entity_name,
    referenced_object_type_desc = o1.type_desc,
    referenced_server_name, referenced_database_name    
FROM
    sys.sql_expression_dependencies sed
INNER JOIN
    sys.objects o ON sed.referencing_id = o.[object_id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    sys.objects o1 ON sed.referenced_id = o1.[object_id]
WHERE
    referenced_entity_name = 'Staff'
    AND referenced_server_name IS NULL
    AND referenced_database_name IS NULL
ORDER BY
    o.name
```

which lists all the objects on `MyDB` which reference my Staff Table

I know that my `Staff` table is used on another database inside a stored procedure, `MySVR.MySecDB.dbo.spMyDB_Staff`. To confirm it, I alter the PDO connection string and rerun the query but with `referenced_database_name = 'MyDB'` to make sure I get only results that reference `MySVR.MyDB.dbo.Staff` and not `MySVR.MySecDB.dbo.Staff`.

The problem however is how would I detect if `Staff` is being referenced in `MySecDB` or any other database outside `MyDB` for me to use do this? Likewise how would I detect if my table is being referenced on another server like in `MyOtherSVR.anotherDBDB.dbo.spMySVR_MyDB_Staff`?

I did think about running the query on every server and database (altering the PDO connection string in a loop) and checking if I got any results but that seems excessive to me.

So is there a way to tell if a table is being referenced in another database / server?

Comment: If you have a list of all servers and all databases in the world (or *your* world, at least), then yes. Script all SQL and parse it for object references. Otherwise, it's a little like asking how I can find out whether or not people in China have my phone number. Until they call me, I just don't know, since asking everyone in China is impractical. This is why linked servers (and cross-database access in general) should be treated with care.

Answer (score 0):

References in other databases on the same SQL instance are somewhat easy to find - you could run a similar query to the one you posted against each of the other databases on the instance, assuming you've got sufficient permissions in all databases.

If you don't have access to all the databases on your same instance, then you're stuck.

Beyond that, it's impractical at best & impossible at worst to identify references on other servers. This would only be possible if you both knew of and were an administrator of all servers which could possibly be referencing this database.